# I need to know how to reinstall grub ... from grub rescue prompt

Tags: grub2, grubrescue

I messed my partions up, I deleted all, then made one ext4, then tried to resize that when I did PC beeped n shutdown. Rebooted to grub rescue prompt. All  (# ls  ) shows is hd0  (hd0,msdos0) ... And  ... hd1  (hd1,msdos1). ... My ext2 is hd0,msdos0, but when I try and set prefix hd1 or hd0, it says grub ain't there, and there's no sudo. :(

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you have nothing on your machine and want to Install Ubuntu? (you deleted all partitions and then re-created)

Comment: Well, I guess I can reinstall, didn't want to though.

Comment: In your case, reinstalling will be the easiest course to take...  Sorry!  ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Stuck in grub rescue after Windows install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33180/stuck-in-grub-rescue-after-windows-install)